# Kafka Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient on Kerberized Cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, kerberos, confluent-platform, confluent-schema-registry, apache-kafka-security

i have a kerberized cluster with Kafka on it.
I want to use Confluent Schema Registry with Kafka on cluster.
Launching the Schema Registry from my local pc, everything works just fine.
But when i uploaded it on a machine in the cluster and tried to run from it i get:

**Error**

```
 ERROR Server died unexpectedly:  (io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.rest.SchemaRegistryMain:50)
org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to create new KafkaAdminClient
...
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.common.KafkaException: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)
...
Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: Message stream modified (41)
```

I also tried to run it from another machine on the cluster and i get the same result.

**Schema-registry.properties**

```
listeners=http://0.0.0.0:8081

kafkastore.connection.url=master01.domain.ext:2181,master02.domain.ext:2181

kafkastore.bootstrap.servers=SASL_PLAINTEXT://xxx.domain.ext:6667,SASL_PLAINTEXT://xxx.domain.ext:6667

kafkastore.topic=_schemas

debug=true

kafkastore.sasl.jaas.config=com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required \
   useKeyTab=true \
   storeKey=true \
   keyTab="/path/schema-registry/etc/schema-registry/my-keytab.keytab" \
   principal="kafka/xxx.domain.ext@DOMAIN.EXT";


kafkastore.sasl.kerberos.service.name=kafka
kafkastore.security.protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
kafkastore.sasl.mechanism=GSSAPI
```

**EXECUTION COMMAND:**

```
sudo bash bin/schema-registry-start ./etc/schema-registry/schema-registry.properties
```

**QUESTIONS:**
Why it works in my local pc and not on a machine on cluster?
What should i change?

P.S. i get the same result even trying to run the CMAK yahoo kafka-manager ( using same jaas.confing and same keytab )

Comment: @GiorgosMyrianthous yup, same result

Comment: BTW as i said, it works on my local pc... same stuff, same cluster, same ips ... i dont understand what could be different from one machine to another... 
P.S. the inter-broker communication security protocol is always SASL_PLAINTEXT